# Problem with Mockito - exceptions.verification.WantedButNotInvoked

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, suite

When I put a "VerificationModeFactory.times(2)" in test before, when I run all tests of the class appears this exception:

org.mockito.exceptions.verification.WantedButNotInvoked: 
Wanted but not invoked:
serviceService.getServices();

If I run each test separately or remove "VerificationModeFactory.times(2)" all works.

It's very weird. Could anybody help me?

Comment: Probably not, unless you posted your test code. Or preferably a minimal setup which still reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as if your verification is declared statically - once per test class, instead of once per test method.

Do this:

```
verify(mock, times(2)).did("my thing");
```

or in your case

```
verify(mockService, times(2)).getServices();
```

(BTW, is it important that your class gets the service twice, or is it more important that it used it? Unless you're describing a performance fix, I'd probably concentrate on the value the service provides instead. Using Mockito that way helps keep tests flexible. My 2 cents.)

Comment: In my case, it's a little different, the method I can verify isn't in a mock class.